# Método de una clase con un condicional y una variable local

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una clase en `Javascript` que me permite tener un método. Este método debe contener un condicional ya que dependiendo de si es un círculo a una figura con lados la fórmula va ser distinta. En el método estoy usando unas propiedades no declaradas que se declararán en las clases, cuadrado, círculo, etc...

Como soy bastante nuevo en esto de las clases no sé ni siquiera si puedo añadir un condicional dentro, si puedo crear una variable local en el método, si tengo que declararla en el constructor etc...

¿Podrían aclararme un poco las dudas y el modo de hacerlo?

Como siempre, mil gracias.

```
class Figura{
//Aquí he declarado la clase result. Pero en realidad no sé si es necesario
  constructor(posX, posY, result){
    this._posX = posX;
    this._posY = posY;
    this.result = result;
  }

  get_posX(){
    return this._posX;
  }

  set_posX(x){
    this._posX = x;
  }

  get_posY(){
    return this._posY;
  }

  set_posY(x){
    this._posY = x;
  }


  //Quizá el método no tiene mucho sentido...

  calcularArea(){
    if(this._radio){
      this._result = 2 * Math.PI * 5;
    }else{
      this._result = parseInt(this._lados) * parseInt(this._lado);
    }
    return this._result;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay varios conceptos que no pareces tener claros:

Podemos decir que un método no es más que una función asociada a un objeto. Es decir, una función cualquiera podría ser un método en Javascript. Lo único que varía es cómo se llama. Por tanto, como en cualquier función, puedes usar cualquier tipo de sentencia que sea válida en el lenguaje, con el extra de tener como contexto (`this`) el objeto *dueño* de la función. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```js
'use strict';

function calculoAreaRectangulo(...args) {
  if (this) { //si no se llama como método, this es undefined
    return this.x * this.y;   
  }
  //no se llama como método, asumo que hay dos parámetros
  let x = args[0]; 
  let y = args[1];
  return x * y;
}

//llamo a la función
console.log('Llamada como función', calculoAreaRectangulo(3,4));


//creo un objeto que tiene 3 propiedades, siendo una (area) un método
const rect = {
  x: 12,
  y: 5,
  area: calculoAreaRectangulo
};

console.log('Llamada como método', rect.area());
```

Comment: muchas gracias Pablo, ya he encontrado mi problema. En el método no puedo colocar la barra baja para llamar las propiedades ya que daría error.
 this._lado me da error. debería ser this.lado
Ya he podido comprobar con condicionales, variables locales, etc


Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una buena solución es que uses la herencia. Doy por hecho que Un círculo y un triangulo son figuras, pero no se parecen en nada no? Por lo tanto, puedes tener una clase Figura, con unos datos comunes y una función calcularArea() que puedes sobreescribir en cualquiera de las clases hijas.

Por otro lado, en la función que presentas, estas asignando y devolviendo un valor de la propia clase a la vez, es decir, al calcular el valor del area lo estás asignando a la propiedad de la clase directamente y luego estás devolviendo dicha propiedad (te lo comento por que no se si quieres ese funcionamiento en concreto)

Te pongo un ejemplo breve de la solución que propongo:

```
class Figura{
// código de la clase padre
}

class Circulo extends Figura{
constructor(radio){
    super();
    this.radio = radio;
  };
// Funcion que solo calcula el area
calcularArea(){
     area = 2 * Math.PI * this.radio;
    return area;
  }
}

class Triangulo extends Figura{
constructor(lados){
    super();
    this.lados = lados;
  };

// Funcion que solo calcula el area
calcularArea(){
    area = parseInt(this._lados) * parseInt(this._lado);
    return area;
  }
}
```

Luego solo tendrías que crear los objetos de clase y usar sus funciones.
No se si te servirá de ayuda el ejemplo, es demasiado simplón pero ilustra un poco el apartado de herencias.

Comment: muchas gracias Eduardo, ya he encontrado mi problema. Que de hecho también lo tienes tú. En el método no puedo colocar la barra baja para llamar las propiedades ya que daría error.
 this._lado me da error. debería ser this.lado

Muchas gracias!